# syntax issue with alter database and set command

Tags: sql-server

Hi I'm tying to run an alter database statement and keep getting an error:
(this is to go in a script which will run against a number of databases)

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = db_name()

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1024)


IF (SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = db_name()) = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = N'ALTER DATABASE [' + db_name() + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE';
    SELECT @SQL;
    sp_executesql @SQL;

    SET @SQL = N'ALTER DATABASE [' + db_name() + '] SET ENABLE_BROKER';
    SELECT @SQL;
    sp_executesql @SQL;


    SET @SQL = N'ALTER DATABASE [' + db_name() + '] SET MULTI_USER';
    SELECT @SQL;
    sp_executesql @SQL;

END 

SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = db_name()
```

I keep getting

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'sp_executesql'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near 'sp_executesql'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near 'sp_executesql'.

I'm doing something dumb - but like most syntax problems looking does not give rise to seeing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the `exec` keyword, like this:

```
exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

That's the way how you call another stored procedure from inside a stored procedure (you could also use `EXECUTE`, which does exactly the same). Take care not to confuse it with the `Exec(...)` function ([see also here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/13/sql-server-difference-between-exec-and-execute-vs-exec-use-execexecute-for-sp-always/)).

Answer (score 3):

Calling a stored procedure without EXEC is only allowed as the first line in a batch. Your calls are not.

Have you also considered this construct to do it in one go?

```
SET @SQL = N'
 ALTER DATABASE [' + db_name() + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
 ALTER DATABASE [' + db_name() + '] SET ENABLE_BROKER;
 ALTER DATABASE [' + db_name() + '] SET MULTI_USER;
';
SELECT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Not sure about your comment on the exec being the first line in the batch - i know its true for create - but even you do not have it as the first line... After a bit of testing - its the added EXEC that causing it to work. Dont worry, I'm feeling dumb by missing the exec!

Comment: @Ian P: What it means is you can leave out EXEC *only* for the first code line. Any other stored proc calls requires EXEC.

Comment: Didnt know that - but I suppose it has to be true otherwise highlighting a proc in SSMS and <f5> would not work. Still hopefully I wont forget the exec for another 5 years

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```